# Consul with Nginx, not using docker

Tags: microservices, nginx, consul

I am from development background and totally new to DevOps, I want to setup **consul for service discovery** for my micro-services, services are reverse proxied by **Nginx**. Now I want to configure Nginx with the consul, we are not using dockers as of now.

I have gone through many tutorials but I didn't get much about that how can I configure Nginx with the consul.

Any lead would be appreciated.

Comment: What tutorials?

Comment: tutorials where I can setup consul with nginx, but all the examples are done using docker.

Comment: OK, what URLs did you consult?

Comment: https://ifritltd.com/2017/11/03/service-discovery-with-consul-registrator-nginx/

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/blog/service-discovery-with-nginx-plus-and-consul/

Comment: https://medium.com/@micheldlebeau/use-consul-as-a-load-balancer-with-nginx-b1f6f887677d

Comment: You could add these URLs to the question

Comment: apologize for that, will keep in mind in future

Comment: @030, It would really be very helpful if can get the basic example of nginx and consul, because I have setup consul in my spring application,

Answer (score 2):

I have done this in the past using https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template.

What `consul-template` does it generate a configuration file (for nginx) based on a certain template you provide. And the values that it fills into this template are coming from the configuration stored in `consul`.

Each time your micro-services register themselves in `consul` and need to be addressed in the nginx configuration file, `consul-template` does it for you by changing the file and sending a `SIGHUP` (`kill -1`) to the nginx process that makes it reload nginx configuration.

The repository for `consule-template` contains an example of managing `nginx` https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template/blob/master/examples/nginx.md

---

If you are using *Nginx Plus*, which is the commercial version of Nginx. Then it has support for Consul built-in. https://www.nginx.com/blog/service-discovery-with-nginx-plus-and-consul/ and https://www.nginx.com/blog/service-discovery-nginx-plus-srv-records-consul-dns/ go into depth on this subject.

Comment: I went through these tutorials but didn't get much help because all the things are new for me, means I am beginner in both consul and nginx, can you please provide me a simple basic example with both nginx and consul, I will be heartily thankful to you, because of this I am stuck from last 2 days

Comment: Updated the answer to include a link to an example.